# JavaScript - Using object prototypes to extend the usage of a method?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, prototype

I am very new to JavaScript, and when working with my object's prototype I try to call the current object to extend a method but it is not working. So I google'd my problem but didn't really get anywhere as it is practically impossible to phrase. However, I found the `this` keyword which I thought should work but didn't. Here's what I have:

```
(function( window, document, undefined ) {
    var myObj = function ( ) { }; // not a noop
    var ua = function() { return navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(); }
    function noop() { }; // empty noop function

    myObj.prototype = {
        constructor: myObj,
        renderizr: {
            presto: ua().match(/(opera|presto)/i),
            trident: ua().match(/trident/i), // don't parse "msie" as opera uses this sometimes
            webkit: ua().match(/(chrome|safari|webkit)/i),
            gecko: ua().match(/(firefox|gecko)/i), // don't parse "netscape" as a lot of strings use this
            val: '' // keep empty for now
        }
    };

    // renderizr.val extension
    // use this so the user can print the value of
    // the rendering engine instead of using multiple
    // conditional statements.
        if(this.renderizr.presto) { this.renderizr.val = "Presto" }
        else if(this.renderizr.trident) { this.renderizr.val = "Trident") }
        else if(this.renderizr.webkit) { this.renderizr.val = "Webkit") }
        else if(this.renderizr.gecko) { this.renderizr.val = "Gecko") }

    window.myObj = new myObj();
}( window, document ));
```

This way, you can do `alert(myObj.renderizr.val);` instead of doing monotonous conditional statements.

I don't want to do generic browser name detection because you're only supposed to test for the features which you need, not the browser. However, some rendering engines have different habits for rendering web pages, so I do want to include **engine detection** in my script. (However, I don't suggest using this, like I said, I just want to get to know javascript and how it works, and it's not working!).

So my question is, what am I doing wrong here and how can I fix it? Why doesn't the `this` keyword work?

Comment: Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: You can access it by using `myObj.prototype.renderizr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want those checks inside your constructor:

```
var myObj = function () {
    // renderizr.val extension
    // use this so the user can print the value of
    // the rendering engine instead of using multiple
    // conditional statements.
    if(this.renderizr.presto) { this.renderizr.val = "Presto" }
    else if(this.renderizr.trident) { this.renderizr.val = "Trident" }
    else if(this.renderizr.webkit) { this.renderizr.val = "Webkit" }
    else if(this.renderizr.gecko) { this.renderizr.val = "Gecko" }
};
```

Also, you have some extra `)` inside your `else if` statements, causing syntax errors. Check a working version here: http://jsfiddle.net/SnKSB/.

Answer (score 5):

You are using `this` in a context where you are not in the instance of a `myObj` object. `this` will be the global scope (ie. window).

Also, all your code is running immediately, you are not defining any functions in your `prototype`.

Comment: Okay, so how would I go about that? I can't put a conditional statement inside of a variable scope. And outside of the scope, I can't use `this`. If I use `myObj`, `myObj` is not yet defined. Any ideas on how to correctly do this, *while staying inside of the immediately invoking function expression*?

Comment: Could I set the `prototype` to a function instead of a sub-object? Like: `myObj.prototype = function() { ... if statements... ...methods... }`? Or does `prototype` *have* to be an object?

Comment: @randmath: No, it does not need to be, but a function is certainly a bad idea. Why would you do that?

Comment: Because a function can have conditional statements, but an object can't, because it expects another variable and it's value. Or am I wrong? Is there a way to do this that I'm not aware of?

Comment: @randmath It really looks like you're looking for a constructor function. See my answer.